# How can I stop jQuery from temporarily overlapping borders with the tbody background color when using toggle to show tbody tags?

Tags: jquery, css, background, html-table, toggle

I am using tbody tags to group table rows so that I can show and hide multiple rows at a time.  The toggle animation works fine when the second `<tbody`> does not have a background color, but as soon as I add one, the background color overlaps the border temporarily, before jumping back to its correct position. This gives the undesirable effect of making the border effectively disappear before re-emerging.

[Here is an example in JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggBN9/3/).

This is the structure within the table tag:

```
<tbody class='tbody1'>
    <tr class='tr1'>
        <td>Test1</td>
        <td>Test2</td>
        <td>Test3</td>
        <td>Test4</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody class='tbody2'>
    <tr class='tr2'>
        <td>Test1</td>
        <td>Test2</td>
        <td>Test3</td>
        <td>Test4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='tr3'>
        <td>Test1</td>
        <td>Test2</td>
        <td>Test3</td>
        <td>Test4</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The CSS:

```
body{
    background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);;
}
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.tbody{
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0); /* to prevent border sizing inconsistency */
    background-color: rgb(243,243,243);
}
.tbody1 {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.tbody2{
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

The jQuery:

```
$('.tbody1').click(function(){
    $('.tbody2').toggle(1000);
});
```

Comment: If you need two tbodies with different colors, try applying tbody2's color to table and leave tbody2 transparent, if you have more than three tbodies with different colors, it's not a solution

Comment: Sadly I don't think this would work for me in my actual code because my table has a bit of padding that is separate to any of the tbodies, but thanks, that was very close to a solution (and would probably work in other situations) :)